# extjs grid - Display empty cell value in float column

Tags: extjs3

I have an EditorGrid in which I'm binding data using XML. One of the (*non-editable*) column (say *Quantity*) type is **float**.

Whenever I try to bind XML data with *Quantity* node as empty, a default value of 0 (zero) is displayed in the Grid. Please note, I'm not setting the 'defaultValue' property for that particular column.

Is there any way, I can prevent the column from displaying 0 (zero) and to render it as Empty cell itself ? I thought about using 'renderer' method, but no use!

Does anyone has encountered the same issue before? How can I render an empty cell in a float column?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've personally never ran into the problem before but one of my coworkers warned me about it.  There is a  useNull config on Ext.data.Field that should do the trick.

```
 {name: 'pctChange',  type: 'float', useNull: true}
```

I tested it out on the array grid sample and it appears to be working as expected.

Comment: Thanks. That's Awesome! I should have read the documentation properly! ;) Thanks Again!